# C++ maps exercise

Tags: c++, stl, maps

I started to learn maps in c++ and i am trying to understand them. I thought i did but then i got to this exercise and didn't know how to manage with it .

**Input:** n-the number of the employees;
in n lines input the names of the employees , their surnames and their salaries.

**Output:** In two lines output the name , surname and salary of the employee with the lowest salary and  the name , surname and salary of the employee with the highest salary.

By the way this is not a homework. I am just a student trying to learn programming by myself.

Maps are obviously very important and there might be many out there which can find this question helpful.

Now, i don't know how to make the relation between the name & surname with the salary . 
That's what i did but this is wrong, how can i input values in the map and then make the relation between the key and the mapped values in order to output the required output?? :

```
 int n;

cin>>n;

  long double sales[n],salary[n];
    string name[n],surname[n];
    map<long int,string,string>m(n);
   long int s;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{   cin>>name[i]>>surname[i]>>sales[i];
    s=200+0.06*sales[i];
    m.push_back(s);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't require the use of a map. Nor is one particularly helpful in solving it. Also - you probably already realize this, but your code is utter nonsense, not even remotely close to valid.

Comment: Yes i know that my code is nonsense , but i tried. I wanted to solve this exercise using maps in order to practice. What do you suggest, if not maps?And can you please tell me how is this solved with maps?

Answer (score 0):

You have started it quite well, but there are several important things:

1) Map is two types: key and value. If you need more than just one value in 'value', why not aggregate them:

```
struct Employee { string name; string surname; long double sale; };
std::map<long int, Employee> m;
```

2) If you want to insert the value at key, use `operator[]`:

```
Employee e; cin >> e.name >> e.surname >> e.sale;
... calculate s...
m[s] = e;
```

3) You neither need to define sales, salary, name and surname as an array, nor is that correct. The index in the declration must be constant, or otherwise this is a *VLA* (exists in C99 standard, but not in any C++, at best you have it available as a gcc extension). Anyway, you have all data to be kept in the map, so you can simply use variable as only a temporary storage.

4) By default you have the values sorted increasingly. So the lowest and highest are simply the first and the last element of the map.